# ¿Cómo crear un subdominio en Apache?

Tags: apache, servidor

Tengo todo el contenido de sitio.com en el directorio /var/www/html pero necesito crear un subdominio sub.sitio.com

Me parece que puedo crear un directorio **sub** en /var/www pero no sé que tipo de configuración tengo que poner el Apache.

¿Cómo puedo lograr esto? Mi servidor es ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Esto sin lugar a dudas no funcionará en Ubuntu XD
Debes aclarar en que plataforma te encuentras antes de contestar la pregunta. Debes estar seguro de ello. Ya que por ejemplo. Apache2 no cuenta con los directorios y archivos de configuración obvios en la versión windows
De todos modos, esto sólo funciona con páginas estáticas. Si tu utilizas páginas dinámicas. Los vínculos "se caen" al implementar ssl.

Answer (score 10):

Configurar un subdominio es algo que puedes hacer desde Apache, y es relativamente sencillo, apenas dos pasos:

1. Activa los alojamientos virtuales (virtual hosts):

   1. Abre el fichero de configuración `httpd.conf`
   2. Descomenta la línea para incluir la configuración de virtual hosts:

      > Nota: las rutas pueden no coincidir, encuentra la línea de httpd-vhosts.conf

      ```
      Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
      ```
2. Crea un virtual host apuntando al directorio que quieres que sea tu subdominio:

   1. Abre el fichero de configuración de virtual hosts (`httpd-vhosts.conf`)
   2. Añade un nuevo host virtual al final del fichero (cambiando los valores por los que correspondan):

      ```
      <VirtualHost *:80>
          ServerAdmin admin@email.com
          DocumentRoot "/ruta/a/directorio/del/subdominio"
          ServerName subdominio.misitio.com
          ErrorLog "logs/misitio.com"
          CustomLog "logs/misitio.com" common
      </VirtualHost>
      ```

Reinicia el servicio de Apache para que tome los cambios y ya debería funcionarte sin problemas.